# Help me solve this question from the Maclaurin olympiad.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

So I did the Maclaurin Olympiad yesterday, and, needless to say, I found it very hard. I only properly answered 2 questions with half solutions for 2 more. This was annoying because previously I was getting full marks or near in practice papers.

Question 5 soaked up most of my time and I still have no idea how to approach it.

Let $p$ and $q$ be the lowest and highest prime factors of $n$ respectively. Find all $n$ such that:

$$p^2 + q^2 = n + 9$$

This has been bugging me since I did it.

Any advice on how to proceed?

We were given roughly 20 minutes to solve and write a full solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First suppose $n$ is even.  Then $p=2$ and you have $q^2=n+5$.  Since $q$ divides $n$, you have $q$ divides $5$, so it must be five.
It turns out that $p=2$, $q=5$, $n=20$ is a solution.

Note that if $p=3$ it forces $q$ to be divisible by $3$ and then it wouldn't be prime.  So $p>5.$

Now suppose $n$ is odd.  Then you have $p^2-9 = n-q^2$ so that $q | p-3$ (impossible) or $q| p+3$, which forces $q=p+2$.

Then you have $2p^2+2p+4 = n+9$.  This again force $p=5$ and so $q=7$.  But this leads to $n=65$ whose highest prime factor is $13.$  Therefore the only solution is $n=20$.

EDIT:  Via Henry:  If $p$ and $q$ are allowed to be equal, then $2p^2 = n+9$ and $p^2 | n$.  So that forces $p^2 |9$ and we have another solution $n=9.$

Comment: $n=9$ is a solution

Comment: @Henry Good point.  Stand by.

Comment: Fair enough and +1.  I thought you were going to change one of your existing lines to "Note that if $p=3$ it forces $q$ to be divisible by $3$ and so it must be $3$. So $p=3,q=3,n=9$ is another solution"

Comment: Why does $q|p+3$ force $q=p+2$?

Comment: @J.G.  $q$ greater than $p$ and less than or equal to $3$.  $p+1$ and $p+3$ are even (not prime).  That leaves $q=p+2$

Comment: @Dhdh  $q$ divides $q^2$ and $n$ so it divides $n-q^2$, so it divides the other side which is equal to $(p-3)(p+3).$  And it's prime so it divides one of the factors.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks for explaining the $p+2$ explanation. I've rolled back, except one of your $=$s had to be changed to a $-$.

Comment: @B.Goddard: But if $q = p+2$, it can't divide $p+3$, so it seems you could stop right there with a contradiction.

Comment: @NickMatteo  In a contest, you'll still have to argue why $p+2$ can't divide $p+3.$   I'm not sure it shortens the argument.